# GameMaker Snes Controller Vertical axis not working

Tags: controller, axis, game-maker, gamepad, game-maker-language

I've been trying to figure this out for some time.
Basically I recently purchased some cheap Snes controllers off Amazon. ([https://www.amazon.com/iNNEXT-Nintendo-Controller-Gamestick-Raspberry/dp/B01N7ANDLC/ref=sr_1_9?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1516067256&sr=1-9&keywords=snes+controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N7ANDLC))
They have worked fine on my RaspberryPi, however when trying to use them with GameMaker the horizontal axis (left and right on the d-pad) are being used as every axis.  Everything else works fine (ABXY, shoulder buttons, etc).
I'm not sure if I'm just being stupid or what.
Here's my code:

```
//CREATE EVENT
gp = 4;
gamepad_set_axis_deadzone(gp,0.5)
spd = 8;

//STEP EVENT
x += gamepad_axis_value(gp,gp_axislh) * spd;
y += gamepad_axis_value(gp,gp_axislv) * spd;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally off-brand gamepads have unusual axis mapping on Windows - I'd suggest to try displaying values of all axes (lh/lv/rh/rv) as well as values of dpad and normal buttons.

If tested Pi games were built with SDL components, chances are that they were using [SDL_GameControllerDB](https://github.com/gabomdq/SDL_GameControllerDB) with various gamepad models pre-mapped.

If everything else fails, you can also try the legacy `joystick_` functions which allow to pull additional DirectInput-specific axes.